# Do we need to close Resource Resolver and Session both?

Tags: aem, aem-6

I am getting a ResourceResolver Object from ResourceResolverFactory i.e. I am creating this resourceResolver and I am adapting to Session.

```
Session session = resourceResolver.adaptTo(Session.class);
```

Do I need to close both, the resolver and the session or closing one would be suffice?

```
finally {
    if (session != null && session.isLive()) {
        session.logout();
    }

    if (resourceResolver != null && resourceResolver.isLive()) {
        resourceResolver.close();
    }
}
```

*This question is about "should we be closing both" and  not which to close first*

Comment: Ownership rule applies. you open it --> you close it! Go through the [rules](https://cqdump.wordpress.com/2013/07/23/cq-development-patterns-sling-resourceresolver-and-jcr-sessions/) for clarification

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I close the session before closing the resource resolver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37880336/should-i-close-the-session-before-closing-the-resource-resolver)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `ResourceResolver` will close the underlying `Session` when you call the `ResourceResolver.close()` method.

If you use newer versions of Sling I would advise you to use the `try-with-resource` construct when you use `ResourceResolver`:

```
try (final ResourceResolver resolver = this.getResourceResolver()) {
    [... use resolver here ...]
}
```

Since `ResourceResolver` implements the `AutoClosable` interface it can be used with `try-with-resource`. This will always close the `ResourceResolver` and you will not have to deal with exceptions etc.

Beware that you can only do this with `ResourceResolver`s that you created. If you use the `ResourceResolver` that you get from a `Resource` for example you should not close it. It is considered best practice that only the one who created the `ResourceResolver` should close it.

Answer (score 2):

Closing one will close them both. If you log a message or debug, you will see you don't enter that second if statement.

Comment: Closing resourceResolver close also the session, but it does not work in the same way if you close session only, resourceResolver will still be available and exception "Session is closed" will be thrown whenever the same resourceResolver will be invoked  (AEM caches opened resourceResolver in some pool, so it is possible to get the same resourceResolver when requesting for the resourceResolver)