# Do I need to logout a session that's adapted from a created resolver?

Tags: session, adobe, aem

My resolver is created through ResourceResolverFactory:

```
resolver = getResolverFactory().getServiceResourceResolver(serviceParams);
```

I already have a finally block in my method which closes the resolver.

My question is regarding the session I'm using:

```
Session session = resolver.adaptTo(Session.class);
```

Do I need to logout this session or not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I close the session before closing the resource resolver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37880336/should-i-close-the-session-before-closing-the-resource-resolver)

Comment: You should close resolver, see more at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37880336/should-i-close-the-session-before-closing-the-resource-resolver

Comment: In most cases, if you are creating the resolver, you should close it. And inherently, you should close the session.